# How to convert PHP array to dataframe in R

Tags: php, r, dataframe

I am new to R. I Google it for quite some time, but there are no related information found.

The following array is generated inside my php script.

```
Array
(
    [data_1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 11
            [5] => 12
        }
    [data_2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 34
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 19
            [5] => 1
        }
}
```

I needs to process these values in R. So I want to create a dataframe for this.

like

```
data_frame_values = data.frame(A=data_1,B=data_2)
```

With output like

```
> data_frame_values
    A     B
1   3    34
2   4    5
3   10   10
4   11   19
5   12   1
```

Can anyone show me a way how to do this ?

I am trying to create it with iterating php arrays and string concatenation. I can share my php code if required.

Or I am going with wrong method, is there any other method exists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to be more specific about how you're getting this data from PHP to R. Or are you just trying to replicate this data structure solely in R?

Comment: Use e.g. `JSON` as the common language. Both PHP and R can deal with JSON.

Comment: @joran yes there are many ways like export as csv from php and import in R, encode it to JSON and pass this to R as said by daroczig, pass array as agrument in R command.. etc.. But I dont know whether we can convert php array directly in R dataframe or not. Thanks for your comments joran and daroczig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your PHP array into a CSV file and load that into your R session.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$array = array("data1"=>array(1,2,45,6,4), "data2"=>array(23,4,5,6,1));
writeCSV ("array.csv", $array, array("A", "B"));

function writeCSV ($filename, $array, $columnNames)
{
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $subarray)
        foreach ($subarray as $subkey => $val)
            $newArray[$subkey][$key] = $val;

    $x = "\"".implode("\",\"",$columnNames)."\"\n";
    foreach ($newArray as $key => $subarray)
    {
        $x = $x.($key+1).",";
        $tempArray = array();
        foreach ($subarray as $subkey => $val)
            array_push($tempArray, $val);

        $x = $x.implode(",", $tempArray)."\n";
    }

    $open = fopen($filename, "w+");
    fputs($open, $x);
    fclose($open);
}
?>
```

**R:**

```
x <- read.csv("array.csv");
print(x)
#    A  B
# 1  1 23
# 2  2  4
# 3 45  5
# 4  6  6
# 5  4  1
```

Comment: Thanks thematerik, appreciated your answer. If I cant convert php array directly into R dataframe, this is another good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to create the combined array?

```
$data_r = array();
$data_1 = array(3,4,10,11,12);
$data_2 = array(34,5,10,19,1);
$i = 0;
while ($i < sizeof($data_1))
{
    $data_r[$i] = array( $data_1[$i], $data_2[$i]);
    $i++;
}
print_r($data_r);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is looking for how to do this _in R_, not in PHP.

Comment: Yes joran is right, I already have php array and I need to pass this array to R. But anyway thanks for your efforts Brian.

Comment: OK, as R is then an external program... perhaps it could be called using exec()...